# Software for mining Quarkcoin on 32-bit Windows

Tags: mining-software, quarkcoin

Is there a software for 32-bit Windows to mine Quarkcoins as part of a pool?

Comment: I wander how comes my Q (which seems to be interesting to lots of people >200 views a day) got downgraded? if the person downgrading would be so kind and leave a comment explaining I would be grateful...

Comment: I still yearn for a comparison of profitability of these recent CPU-only coins, such as Primecoin, Quarkcoin and Protoshares...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the right place where you can find the information [bitcointalk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=260031.0)

Comment: Thanks, I looked there but nothing there seems to work on 32 bit (even the versions that seem to be supposed to...)